# .Net Membership and other options……

Tags: c#, .net

For a .net based web application what are all the options available for authorization?

I can use .NET Membership Provider or Windows Identity Framework. Is there any other solution from Microsoft? Any other solutions from third party?

Thank you,
Smith

Comment: You can implement a custom Membership Provider.  What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using something like the "[Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg429786.aspx)" (ACS).  ACS brokers out authentication to various providers (like Live ID, Google, Yahoo, etc) and allows your users to use their existing identities to authenticate with your site.

Comment: That is only for Azure and it is not tagged Azure

Comment: @Blam - it isn't tagged with any deployment platform. Azure is a platform on which this web application could be deployed. Besides, any platform could use ACS.